# JPA: Check if Collection has member with property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

In my software, I have an entity (let's call it `Member`) with a collection of another entity (let's call it `State`). The query I need to write should return all members who have no `State` with a specific property value (e. g. `5`).

Here are the relevant parts of the entities:

```
public class Member {
    @JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID")
    @OneToMany
    private List<State> states;

    @Column
    private String name;
}

public class State {
    @Column
    private int property;
}
```

Note that there is no bidirectional mapping between `Member` and `State`, the mapping is declared on the non-owning side of the relation (`Member`). In SQL I would create a query like this:

```sql
SELECT m.name
FROM Member m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM State s
    WHERE
        m.id = s.member_id
        AND s.property = 5
);
```

But I don't know of any way to achieve the same thing in JPQL without having a mapping on the owning side of the relation. Is there any way to achieve this without having to bother with bidirectional mappings?

Answer (score 7):

JPA allows to use collection references in subquery from clauses, so you can use this:

```
SELECT m.name 
FROM Member m 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM m.states s 
    WHERE s.property = 5
)
```

This will produce exactly the SQL you want.

Comment: Selecting properties from collections also works with joins: `SELECT m.id, s.id FROM Member m LEFT JOIN State s ON s.id IN (SELECT mState.id FROM m.states mState)`. If you do not need the property but the entity itself, JPQL provides MEMBER OF operator as alternative to IN operator: `SELECT m.id, s.id FROM Member m LEFT JOIN State s ON s MEMBER OF m.states`

Comment: The `member of` syntax is fine as that usually renders to a SQL `exists` as well, but the `in` predicate can have different performance characteristics. Not though, that the question was specifically about additionally filtering the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
select m.name from Member m where not exists(
    from Member m1 join m1.states s where s.property = 5
)
```

or

```
select m.name from Member m where m.id not in(
    select m1.id from Member m1 join m1.states s where s.property = 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write native query like this

> select name from Member where member_id not in ( select id from states
> where property = 5)